# I am a newbie with java and I am trying to connect to a derby database. I am using netbeans 7.4

Tags: java

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class DBConnect {


public static void main(String[] args) {

    String host = ("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Employees");
    String uName = ("sa");
    String uPass = ("saa");
try {

    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(host, uName, uPass);
}
catch ( SQLException err) {
    System.out.println( err.getMessage());
}
}

}
```

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - exception java.sql.SQLException is never th [missing fragment here]

Comment: Please finish what you're saying

Comment: Also, when defining a string you don't need to use parentheses to wrap it. i.e. `String uName = "sa";`

Comment: Are you able to connect with these credentials in the `services` tab of Netbeans?  I would double check that you have that correct first before trying to get connected in code.

Answer (score 1):

The code looks fine except that you misspelled `DriverManager` as `DriveManager`. (Notice the missing 'r')

Comment: In my haste to tell him/her of the spelling error, I made about three of them myself. :)

Comment: You may want to use the Eclipse IDE .. it will catch these errors.